# calculate age from dob and given date in pandas and make age as zero if dob is missing in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a data frame as shown below.
df:

```
cust_id         lead_date            dob
1               2016-12-25           1989-12-20
2               2017-10-25           1980-09-20
3               2016-11-25           NaN
4               2014-04-25           1989-12-20
5               2019-12-21           NaN
```

From the above I would like to calculate age as difference of lead_date with dob in years.

if dob is NaN then make age as 0.

Expected output:

```
cust_id         lead_date            dob              age
1               2016-12-25           1989-12-20       27
2               2017-10-25           1980-09-20       37
3               2016-11-25           NaN              0
4               2014-04-25           1989-12-20       25
5               2019-12-21           NaN              0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
# convert to datetime type
df['lead_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.lead_date)
df['dob'] = pd.to_datetime(df.dob)

df['age'] = (df.lead_date.dt.year - df.dob.dt.year).fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
   cust_id  lead_date        dob   age
0        1 2016-12-25 1989-12-20  27.0
1        2 2017-10-25 1980-09-20  37.0
2        3 2016-11-25        NaT   0.0
3        4 2014-04-25 1989-12-20  25.0
4        5 2019-12-21        NaT   0.0
```

Comment: added new question pls look into this during your free time.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63323668/append-a-column-from-one-df-to-another-based-on-the-date-column-on-both-dfs-pa